# CMOS XOR propagation delay in Python

Tags: python, xor

I have been struggling with something relatively simple but haven't yet figure out a good way to solve it.

I need to simulate, at a very high level, XOR gates. I have two streams of 0/1 and want to do piece-wise XOR and that's the easy bit. Now I wanted to add a limitation of real life CMOS XOR gates, simply the propagation delay.
This means that if the input change so quickly that the XOR would have to transition faster than a certain delay, the XOR output would not transition, therefore missing some of the transitions at the output.
Googling a bit, I think I found a MATLAB tool that does that (https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/cmosxor.html) and I would like something similar to put into my python codes.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you been able to simulate the gate without the delay? If you have, I would include that code in your question

Comment: Just using the logic XOR function to do it. That of course worse fine but is too ideal. I need to simulate the “failure” when the input transitions are too close to one another

Comment: I think I have not explained the issue correctly. The propagation delay is not just a simple time shift. So, let's say one of the input changes 0->1 and the second input changes 0->1 after only, let's say, 3 time stamps. But the XOR propagation delay I want to simulate corresponds to 5 time stamps. The idea output performs 2 changes 0->1->1 without issue. A real XOR with such propagation delay will stay 0 because it takes 5 time stamps to perform the first transition but by the 3 time stamp, the transition is reversed hence keeping the output to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For high level simulation, you could apply a *time wheel*. The time wheel has a fixed number of slots corresponding to multiples of a basic time unit (fractions of a nanosecond). Attached to each slot is a list of events scheduled for this time.

An event is a transition of an input or output line. The simulation algorithm works around the wheel and calculates subsequent events. These are stored in their respective slot lists. Time wraps around at the end of the wheel horizon. Events are removed from their lists after processing.

**Example:**
Input `A` of an `XOR` gate goes from `0` to `1` at time `8`. This causes the output `F` of the gate to toggle its polarity `2` time slots later.

It is possible to use different delays depending on the direction of the transition (`0->1` or `1->0`). Typically, the delay also depends on the number of inputs driven by the gate output. The granularity or time accuracy of the simulation is determined by the number of slots in the wheel. The more slots the smaller is the timestep per slot. It is essential that the wheel horizon is big enough to prevent double wraps.

The following depicts the difference between discrete and analog simulation:

[image]

If you require the accuracy of analog simulation, you can either resort to a fully analog simulator, or you could assume exponential transitions and calculate the time when certain threshold are reached.

Comment: Never heard of time wheels. Can you give me something to read and try? Thanks!

Comment: Just think of an array of (possibly empty) lists. If the array has 100 elements, you put new event for time `t` in the list of element `t mod 100`.

Comment: I think I have not explained the issue correctly. 
The propagation delay is not just a simple time shift. So, let's say one of the input changes 0->1 and the second input changes 0->1 after only, let's say, 3 time stamps. But the XOR propagation delay I want to simulate corresponds to 5 time stamps. The idea output performs 2 changes 0->1->1 without issue. A real XOR with such propagation delay will stay 0 because it takes 5 time stamps to perform the first transition but by the 3 time stamp, the transition is reversed hence keeping the output to 0.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to draw the concept. It's it very close to my issue but not quite.
I have an example of what I want to simulate:
![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/JCXG7TP)

If you see, last transitions of the input happen too close in time, the XOR misses both of them because it would require it to transition too fast. 

That's what I need to simulate. I thought about doing first an idea XOR and then add a low-pass filter. But no success yet